# Change the keys in Django ModelChoiceField when populated from a ForeignKeyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I've been looking at this article: [how to populate dropdown list in Django from a foreignkey model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675069/how-to-populate-dropdown-list-in-django-from-a-foreignkey-model/30675229#30675229) and I am looking for the next step.  Here are my models:

```
class customer(models.Model):
    custid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=245)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class job(models.Model):
    jobid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    custid = models.ForeignKey('customer')
    description = models.TextField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Here is my form:

```
class JobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = job
        exclude = ['jobid']
```

Here is my view for this page:

```
def receivables(request):
    """Renders the receivables page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    job_list = job.objects.all()
    cus_list = customer.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        jobForm = JobForm(request.POST)
        if jobForm.is_valid():
            jobForm.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/receivables/')
    else:
        jobForm = JobForm() 

    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'customers':cus_list,
        'jobs':job_list,
        'job_form':jobForm
        })
    return render(
        request,
        'app/receivables.html',
        context
    )
```

My problem is that whenever I call `{{ jobs.custid }}` in my template, I get a dropdown box that looks like this:

[image: Drop Down Screenshot]

I want to have those choices populate using the `'name'` field from my customers view.  Any ideas?

Comment: this post should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33844887/3755845

Answer (score 1):

Add `__str__`(`__unicode__` for Python2.x) method to your customer model:

```
class customer(models.Model):
    custid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=245)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ for python2.x
        return self.name
```